# JavaScript dynamic list

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I am trying to create a dynamic list where a person can add items, one line at the time, each line with the control to delete or add a new one.

My list would be of 10 items and the first one is always mandatory.

I managed to pull it off till the point where a user can add all 10 lines but if he tries to delete or something everything goes south... Can someone help me with this without jQuery?

I also created an example in JSFiddle but it doesn't work there... never the less he is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/Zx8hc/2/

Thank you very much in advance.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Doc</title>

        <style type="text/css">

            #usersform {
                display: table;
            }

            .divtr {
                display: none;
            }

            .divtd {
                display: table-cell;
                padding-top: 10px;
            }

            #presUser_1 {
                display: table-row!important;
            }

        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function addUsersForm(x) {
                var y = "presUser_" + x;
                var z = "addUserButton_" + (x - 1);
                var t = "removeUserButton_" + (x - 1);

                document.getElementById(y).style.display = "table-row";
                document.getElementById(z).style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById(t).style.display = "inline-block";

            }

            function removeUsersForm(x) {
                var y = "presUser_" + x;

                document.getElementById(y).style.display = "none";

            }
        </script>   

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="usersForm">
            <div class="divtr" id="presUser_1">
                <div class="divtd">Age <input type="text"></div>
                <div class="divtd">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addUserButton_1" title="Add" onClick="addUsersForm(2);">Add</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removeUserButton_1" title="Delete this" onClick="removeUsersForm(1);">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="divtr" id="presUser_2">
                <div class="divtd">Age <input class="textAge" name="page_2" id="page_2" type="text"></div>
                <div class="divtd">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addUserButton_2" title="Add" onClick="addUsersForm(3);">Add</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removeUserButton_2" title="Delete this" onClick="removeUsersForm(2);">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="divtr" id="presUser_3">
                <div class="divtd">Age <input class="textAge" name="page_3" id="page_3" type="text"></div>
                <div class="divtd">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addUserButton_3" title="Add" onClick="addUsersForm(4);">Add</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removeUserButton_3" title="Delete this" onClick="removeUsersForm(3);">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="divtr" id="presUser_4">
                <div class="divtd">Age <input class="textAge" name="page_4" id="page_4" type="text"></div>
                <div class="divtd">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addUserButton_4" title="Add" onClick="addUsersForm(5);">Add</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removeUserButton_4" title="Delete this" onClick="removeUsersForm(4);">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="divtr" id="presUser_5">
                <div class="divtd">Age <input class="textAge" name="page_5" id="page_5" type="text"></div>
                <div class="divtd">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addUserButton_5" title="Add" onClick="addUsersForm(6);">Add</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removeUserButton_5" title="Delete this" onClick="removeUsersForm(5);">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="divtr" id="presUser_6">
                <div class="divtd">Age <input class="textAge" name="page_6" id="page_6" type="text"></div>
                <div class="divtd">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addUserButton_6" title="Add" onClick="addUsersForm(7);">Add</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removeUserButton_6" title="Delete this" onClick="removeUsersForm(6);">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="divtr" id="presUser_7">
                <div class="divtd">Age <input class="textAge" name="page_7" id="page_7" type="text"></div>
                <div class="divtd">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addUserButton_7" title="Add" onClick="addUsersForm(8);">Add</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removeUserButton_7" title="Delete this" onClick="removeUsersForm(7);">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="divtr" id="presUser_8">
                <div class="divtd">Age <input class="textAge" name="page_8" id="page_8" type="text"></div>
                <div class="divtd">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addUserButton_8" title="Add" onClick="addUsersForm(9);">Add</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removeUserButton_8" title="Delete this" onClick="removeUsersForm(8);">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="divtr" id="presUser_9">
                <div class="divtd">Age <input class="textAge" name="page_9" id="page_9" type="text"></div>
                <div class="divtd">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addUserButton_9" title="Add" onClick="addUsersForm(10);">Add</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removeUserButton_9" title="Delete this" onClick="removeUsersForm(9);">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="divtr" id="presUser_10">
                <div class="divtd">Age <input class="textAge" name="page_10" id="page_10" type="text"></div>
                <div class="divtd">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removeUserButton_10" title="Delete this" onClick="removeUsersForm(10);">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

========================
EDIT

More explanations... What I mean is that if a person starts to delete rows but not in the right order the "add" button disappears, or the rows can be added only a "limited" number of times, weird stuff if you try to find it's tickles you will discover. I was just asking if you guys with experience in this stuff can tell me a more easy way to do this, because I bet there is one.

- When you add all 10 lines the "add" button disappears, but if there are added less than 10 lines there should be the add button on the last of the lines, right?
- Also, when adding / deleting I notice some of the lines will simply not want do disappear...

Comment: here's a working fiddle with your code: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zx8hc/3/) anyway everything seems to be working fine.. both add and delete buttons work properly. can you please explain what you mean with "everything goes south.."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's a fiddle** to dynamically add and remove objects from a list: http://jsfiddle.net/Zx8hc/6/

The `addUsersForm` function adds a new element, assigns a new id and adds it and appends it to the form.

Something to note here is this:

```
this.id = this.id  || 2; //Starts with 2, because the existing element has id 1
```

This is a useful thing to remember:) This says that you either set this.id to itself (not changing the value), or if it's undefined, you set it to 2 (the starting value). At the end you increase the id value by one. By using this, you store this on the function itself, rather than creating a new variable each time the function is run.

The `removeUsersForm` function takes in an id, and removes that element.

**Update**: This is a better fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zx8hc/9/. This works by encapsulating the page controls in a controller object.

Comment: You are definitely awesome... The code is perfect for me; But only as a caprice, would there be any way to keep the "add" button only on the last of the elements?

Comment: OK, I figured it out, I delete the link from the "prototype" to "add" and I keep it in the first div only, It looks neat now. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem:) I don't often use plain old javascript myself, so it was fun. I agree with the poster @vol7tron that AngularJS is better suited for creating dynamic content like this, though I opted to not use any frameworks as I think that's a good way to start out if you're new to javascript.

Comment: Hi again, I just understood the "this.id" thing and I was wondering, would it be the same thing to have a global variable (outside a function) and use it as a counter? Or that would be a pain in the arse when reloading page/re sending form, etc?

Comment: Yes that would be the same:) It's just that in general, one wants to avoid global variables as much as possible. When the javascript code gets large, and you have a lot of global variables, it's easy to introduce errors. You might for example name one of your local variables the same as a global one and introduce random behaviour and causing headache. It's also easier to see that the variable "belongs" to the code within the function when it's not global. It's not as trivial to see where a global variable is being used. Hope that clears something up, at least ;)

Comment: I updated the answer with better solution at the bottom. `this` is a keyword that references the object you're currently "in". The problem with my original one, is that when you have global functions, then `this` = the global object, AKA `window`. When you encapsulate the entire thing in it's own object you can set the id attribute directly, and `this` no longer is `window`, but the userController! :)

Comment: Perfect job. I am using this example now, and even if it works exactly the same I bet it's better solution. Thanks.
 The only question I have now regarding this newly and dynamically created inputs, is how to collect all the data from them (since I cannot know how many the user has created) and store it in vars with PHP. Is there any quick answer for that or you recommend me opening a new thread?

Answer (score 0):

[New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zx8hc/7/)

This is a quick example to show you how to accomplish a similar effect with `AngularJS`.  My Angular is not perfect, but it should suffice to show that you do not need all the repetition of HTML, nor do you have to manually specify JS target IDs.

---

Note: my previous answer was a little hasty as I take it you're new to web development and could have used a much more helpful response.

Comment: Maybe in XHTML... but in HTML? HTML5?

Comment: @user3529213 I don't think it's needed for HTML/HTML5, but for JSFiddle, which uses syntax highlighters it helps.  The only reason I put that there was because Stack Overflow complains about links to JSFiddle without including code

Comment: OK, I will take that into account next time I post in JSFiddle, thank you.

Comment: I saved you Fiddle on my computer I hope to personalize it and be able to use it on the web I am working now. You are right, I am new to development of webpages. Also take note on the AngularJS and the MVP/templates thingy... Could you give me a hint and put me on right direction on where should I look for more info on that matter? Does it have any special name it goes by? ("Templating" (ha), """prototyping?""").
Also, thank you very much for the effort you put on doing it. I appreciate it.